# replace unreachable javascript in a web page

Tags: javascript, web

When I tried to access a web page from a site which is not controlled by me. I found that one page did not display well. And the cause is that one javascript which is referred by the page is unreachable in my environment. Well, I  have a copy of the unreachable javascript locally. The question is, can I load my local javascript to the web page to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: you might be able to load it using a bookmarklet, but what do you mean by "unreachable" ?

Comment: "Unreachable" means I cannot access the javascript file via its url(say its http://path.to.file.js). While I have a local copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the hints from [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), I resloved this issue by creating a bookmarklet (refer to [How To Make a Bookmarklet For Your Web Application](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application;) for more detail about bookmarklet). say that you want to replace javascript file javascriptFileA (url: http://url.to.javascriptFileA) in web page webpageA. Create a bookmarklet with the following script. And click the bookmarklet after loading the webpageA. the javascript file will javascriptFileA  be added to the web page.

```
javascript: (function(){
if(frames.length > document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length){
    alert('cannot use bookmarklet.');
}
else{
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src','http://url.to.javascriptFileA');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    //alert('Load done...');
    }
})();
```

Comment: You can even improve it by testing to see if the script is already loaded